# Tutorial for introducing someone to OOP

Tags: java, oop

I have someone I need to train in Java.
That person is well versed with classic c, and matlab programming, but does not know OOP.
I would send them to the Sun online tutorial, but it seems to explain OOP very briefly.

I am looking for a good online / PDF tutorial on the subject. Preferably, but not a must, in Java.

Comment: there are tons of online OOP tutorials. just google a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the on-line material from the Object Oriented programming course at Brown. It includes both lectures, assignments and labs.

http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs015/

Answer (score 1):

When I study about Java and OOP, I found the following books very much useful:

1. **Head First Java** By Bert Bates, Kathy Sierra, Published by O'Reilly Media.
2. **Objects First With Java A Practical Introduction Using BlueJ** By David J. Barnes & Michael Kölling, Published by Prentice Hall